# SMTP Python, error "name 'Sender' is not defined. First time using SMTP

Tags: python, email, raspberry-pi, smtp

Attempting to use SMTP Python on my raspberry pi for the first time, I'm almost there but when it goes to send an email, I get the error "name 'Sender' is not defined". First time using SMTP please help.

The purpose of the code is to generate a random email address and send them an email.

Error message:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\jjllo\Documents\Emailbot\emailbot_smtp.py", line 70, in <module>
    sender.sendmail(sendTo, emailSubject, emailContent)
NameError: name 'sender' is not defined`

Code:

```
import smtplib
import random
import string
import time
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

#Email Variables
SMTP_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com' #Email Server (don't change!)
SMTP_PORT = 587 #Server Port (don't change!)
GMAIL_USERNAME = 'everettmahaj@gmail.com' #change this to match your gmail account
GMAIL_PASSWORD = 'puttyslime123'  #change this to match your gmail password

class Emailer:
    def sendmail(self, recipient, subject, content):

        #Create Headers
        headers = ["From: " + GMAIL_USERNAME, "Subject: " + subject, "To: " + recipient,
                   "MIME-Version: 1.0", "Content-Type: text/html"]
        headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

        #Connect to Gmail Server
        session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
        session.ehlo()
        session.starttls()
        session.ehlo()

        #Login to Gmail
        session.login(GMAIL_USERNAME, GMAIL_PASSWORD)

        #Send Email & Exit
        session.sendmail(GMAIL_USERNAME, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + content)
        session.quit

#Sends an email to the "sendTo" address with the specified "emailSubject" as the subject and             
"emailContent" as the email content.

count = 0
while count < 10:

        #Generate address
        x = random.randint(0, 1)
        y = random.randint(0, 1)
        z = random.randint(0, 1)
        if x == 0:
                prefix1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                prefix2 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                first = ""
        if x == 1:
                prefix1 = random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase)
                prefix2 = ""
                first = ""
        if x == 1 and y == 1:
                prefix1 = ""
                prefix2 = ""
                first = random.choice(open('first.txt').readlines()) 

        last = random.choice(open('last.txt').readlines())

        last = last.strip()
        first= first.strip()

        if z ==0:
                first = first + "."

        msg = MIMEText(u'''<a href="http://adfoc.us/49591773263718">Click here to unsubscribe.        
        </a>''','html')

        sendTo = (prefix1 + prefix2 + first + last + "@gmail.com")
        emailSubject = "Click here to un-subscribe."
        emailContent = msg
        sender.sendmail(sendTo, emailSubject, emailContent)
        print("Email Sent to:", sendTo, "at", time.ctime())
        time.sleep(0.1)
```

Comment: The fact is `sender is not defined`. What do you expect `sender` for? Define it in your code.

Answer (score 0):

`NameError: name 'sender' is not defined` means that `'sender' is not defined`. As I guess is that it should be an `Emailer` object. So maybe you want to declare it:

```py
count = 0
sender = Emailer()
while count < 10:
    # --snip--
```

*Tip: Since `Emailer` object only has one function, make it a function like moving `sendmail` out of `Emailer` and call that function directly.*